# How can I remove product from cart on woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$demoid = '28'echo; "<div class='product__action'>
            <a href='".$woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item( $demoid)."'>
                <span class='lnr lnr-trash'></span>
            </a>
            <p> $".$price."</p>
        </div>
    </div>"
```

Everything is okay until here but when i click remove from cart it's not working I want to make when customer click here

```
<a href='".$woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item( $demoid)."'>
    <span class='lnr lnr-trash'></span>
</a>
```

the product should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I found it finally but it's not working correctly actually it is but it's remove product with all quantity I want just delete 1 quantity

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url($values['key'])
```